# How to access the text inside these tags in python?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, data-science

I have a dataset where I tagged the noun phrases. How to find these tags and extract the data from inside the tag.

```
در
همین
حال
<coref coref_coref_class="set_0" coref_mentiontype="ne" markable_scheme="coref" coref_coreftype="ident">
نجیب
الله
خواجه
عمری
</coref>
<coref coref_coref_class="set_0" coref_mentiontype="np" markable_scheme="coref" coref_coreftype="ident">
سرپرست
وزارت
تحصیلات
عالی
افغانستان
</coref>
گفت
که


 def ex_feature(text):
    for w in text:
        if w.startswith("<coref") and w.endswith("</coref>"):
            print(w)
```

Comment: use beautifulsoup

Comment: but it is a text file not an XML or HTML file to use beautifulsoup. Can I use beautifulsoup for text file as well?

Comment: XML file is a text file with tags to organize the informations. You have a text file which uses tags to organize the information. Looks pretty close to XML to me ;)

Comment: yes, you are right, but I convert it to another format. Currently it is .tt format. so the xml parser in beautifulSoup not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
import re
print(re.findall(r'<coref.*?>(.*?)</coref>', text, re.S))
```

Comment: It is looking great. I tried it, it gives me this with "\n" to each word. '['\nنجیب\nالله\nخواجه\nعمری\n،\n', '\nسرپرست\nوزارت\nتحصیلات\nعالی\nافغانستان\n] '

Comment: How to remove the '\n' from the output.

Comment: Try `ans.replace('\n', '')`

Comment: It is a list, does not have replace attribute.

Comment: `list(map(lambda x: x.replace('\n', ''), ans))`

Comment: one more problem is left, for example, if the two tag is in one sentence, how can I define that the first two tag belongs to the first sentence or maybe there will be tags that one tag is in one sentence and the other tag is on another sentence, so it should count the number of the sentence for each two tags. I tried but I could not find the result.If you kindly have any idea, please help me. Thanks